# ASP.NET MVC5 F12 not creating views

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have Resharper8 and VS2012 ... I upgraded my project to MVC5 and updated all the references in the web.config but when I press F12 on a View in a controller, it takes me to the function definition and not the View file itself. Creating new views aren't automatic either, what happened and how do I get it back?

Comment: Did you find any solutions yet? I have the same problem and I have tried so many things to resolve this.

Comment: FWIW I have the same problem with Resharper8 and Visual Studio 2013. I tried disabling Web Essentials and Redgate plugins and reinstalling R# but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this thanks to the super fast support at JetBrains.  The error occurs when you update to MVC 5.2 via nuget.  To fix it:

ReSharper | Extension Manager | Updates | Find "ReSharper.ExternalAnnotations" plugin | Update it to the latest version | Restart Visual Studio

http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/40213828-Missing-ReSharper-features-after-applying-MVC-5-2-nuget-update-